# How to read a specific column of a csv file which has space in Ipython

Tags: python, csv, ipython, jupyter

I have tried `File.Column` Name, `File.Column/Name` and File."Column Name"

Comment: You might start by reading the docs on the csv module.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Using pandas or another method of accessing the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using a pandas dataframe, if that is the case, use:

```
df['Column Name']
```